# What is the difference between locale using Locale.getDefault() and context.getResources().getConfiguration().locale?

Tags: android, locale

Is there any difference between String returned by:

```
Locale.getDefault().toString()
```

and

```
context.getResources().getConfiguration().locale.toString()
```

Asking because I suspect this is causing a bug in app, something which worked before using `Locale.getDefault().toString()` is not working anymore with `context.getResources().getConfiguration().locale.toString()`, on some US devices. But not sure if this is the reason.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Locale.getDefault().toString()` and 
`context.getResources().getConfiguration().locale.toString()` should return the same value.

The only major difference between the two is that the `Locale.getDefault()` can be *directly* overridden by `Locale.setDefault(locale)`. (Which will also affect `context.getResources().getConfiguration().locale.toString()`)

Comment: Hm. Well, I thought the same. But as said it could possible be causing an error. But maybe it's something else. I'll check and come back to this thread, thanks.

Comment: What exactly are the errors/bugs that appear when you work with these methods?

Comment: Uhm, well, it's complicated... basically it's that somewhere I expect the locale to be (exactly) en_US, for US devices which "english" or "english (United States) setting (for devices with english (other country) the locale is expected to be en_XX). And something related with this is not working (webservice etc.). But I did many changes and maybe the issue is somewhere else.